# Reading\modifying a graphql

Tags: python-2.7, graphql

I want to be able to check, validate and modify some existing graphql statements.  For example I generate the below using a template and getting data from Elasticsearch

```
mutation  {
  productUpdate(
    input: {
      id: "gid://shopify/Product/1388950487084",
      tags: ["one","two"]
    } 
  )
  {
    product {
      id
      tags
    }
    userErrors {
      field,
      message
    }
  }
}
```

From that, what I want to do is say check on the value of id, for example access this value

mutation.productUpdate.input.id

I am only posting to a third party, I am not hosting the schema or anything like that.

To be able to access and modify the payload, do I need to use a library?  And if so, what would be the most lightweight?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you control this query?  It's not usually a best practice to directly embed values in the query like this; instead you'd use [GraphQL variables](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables) to make it possible to pass in key values separately from the query proper.

```graphql
mutation ProductUpdate($id: ID!, $tags: [String!]) {
  productUpdate(input: {id: $id, tags: $tags}) {
    product { id tags }
    userErrors { field message }
  }
}
```

---

If you pick apart the GraphQL spec in some detail, it has several major parts: an object model; a grammar for parsing GraphQL schemas and queries; validation rules for ensuring a query matches a schema; execution rules to actually run a query against a schema; and the HTTP transport part (only kind of in the spec).  Mostly the GraphQL libraries I've seen (in several languages) lump all of this together, but advanced users can pick the pieces apart.

What you're describing is probably possible in any language with a reasonably mature GraphQL library, but it's not going to have a super-convenient syntax.  Abstractly, you'll need to:

1. Get the schema from the service (there is a standard GraphQL query to retrieve it and many libraries can accept that JSON form as their input).
2. Parse your proposed query, using the library of your choice, into an *abstract syntax tree* (AST).
3. Find the value you're interested in in the AST structure; mutate it, if that's what you're trying to do and it's allowed.
4. Validate the query against the AST using the GraphQL library.
5. Serialize the AST back into a GraphQL query.
6. Submit the query to the server the way you normally would.

If you don't control the query, the variable scheme I described initially could cause a little bit of trouble.  You might discover (as in my sample query) that the value of a field is a variable reference.  You can rewrite it, but [it's a validation error to have unused variables](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-All-Variables-Used), so you might be forced to (maybe) remove variables as well, which can get hairy.

Comment: Although not the answer I was directly looking for, the approach to add the values in as variables solved my problem, and now means I am doing this in a more flexible way